Geometric interpretation of flags and the role of the rook monoid and Kazhdan–Lusztig theory in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$
Let $G = GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, $B$ be its Borel subgroup, and $P$ a parabolic subgroup. The space $G/B$ corresponds to complete flags in $ \mathbb{C}^n$, and $G/P$ corresponds to partial flags. The symmetric group $ S_n $ encodes the $ B $-equivariant orbit structure of $ G/B $, and for $ G/P $, a subgroup of $ S_n $ encodes the corresponding object.
For $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) $, the group $G$ acts by conjugation, and the geometric structure involves stratifications by ranks. I have the following questions:

Flags in $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) $:

What "kind of flags" naturally arise when studying the $ B $-orbits on $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) $?
Are these flags directly related to partial flags that are not complete flag, or is there another geometric description?


Role of the Rook Monoid:

The rook monoid generalizes $ S_n $ by incorporating partial permutations and is the monoid Weyl group. Geometrically, what does the rook monoid capture in $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) $?
Does it encode partial flag degenerations, block structures of matrices, or stratifications by orbit closures under conjugation?
How does this relate to the geometry of $ G/P $ and partial flag varieties?


Kazhdan–Lusztig Theory for Monoids:
In the context of the rook monoid, there is a Kazhdan–Lusztig theory developed by M. Putcha (e.g., "Monoid Hecke algebras"(MSN), involving Kazhdan–Lusztig bases, an involution, and Kazhdan–Lusztig polynomials.

What does this theory mean geometrically?
Is it merely an extension of the classical Kazhdan–Lusztig theory for $ S_n $, or does it play a deeper role in the geometry of $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) $ and its orbit structure?
If it plays an important role, what are those roles? Can you provide some directions or indications for how this theory connects to geometry, orbit stratifications, or flag varieties?



Any insights, references, or directions to explore would be greatly appreciated!

The rook monoid describes cells in the Bruhat decomposition of the matrix ring $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. See Exercise 4.3.9 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8356v7 , for example. (I also remember seeing more on this in a recent paper by Hugo Woerdeman, but I cannot find it at the moment.)

Yes. It gives Bruhat decomposition for Monoid. What it could be in terms of "flags"?

When you say "for $G/P$, a subgroup of $S_n$ encodes the corresponding object", I'm not sure what you mean.  First, is the corresponding object $B\backslash G/P$ or $P\backslash G/P$?  Second, either way, the orbits are usually parameterised by appropriate minimal-length coset representatives, not, I think, by a subgroup.

I meant B\G/P. And you are right. The orbits are parametrised by minimal length coset representatives. Thank you for pointing it. @LSpice.

Related to your question 1: I don't know if that is what you are looking for, but if you let $G$ act on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and consider one orbit, say $\mathcal{O}_x=G\cdot x$ with $x\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, then you get an action of $B$ on $G/Z_x$ where $Z_x$ is the centralizer of $x$, and there is a $1$ to $1$ correspondence between $B$-orbits on $G/Z_x$ and $Z_x$-orbits on the flag variety $G/B$ (preserving inclusions of orbit closures). This is at least one situation where "flags" come into the picture when considering the action of $G$ on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$...
